# best sql client for linux *box window manager

Tags: rdbms, sqlclient, archlinux

I am using ARCH Linux and Awesome3 WM.

I am looking for a good sql client for multi database include mysql postgre oracal.

Squirrel sql seems good, but I got a blank window after launch it.

Any solution for this problem or there is another better client for me?

Answer (score 0):

http://henplus.sourceforge.net/

It's not a GUI, but it works with any database that has a JDBC driver (including MySQL, PostgreSQL, and Oracle), and I like it.

Answer (score 0):

Several tiling window managers might have problems with java applications. Take a look at this page: http://awesome.naquadah.org/wiki/Problems_with_Java.
Especially try the workaround using `wmname`.

As a DB frontend you might try [DbVisualizer](http://www.dbvis.com/). If you are using Eclipse to develop your application, "Eclipse SQL Editor" might be of interest. Sorry, Stackoverflow spam protection doesn't let me to provide a hyperlink for that one.